# "de gozaru" in a casual speech

Tags: word-choice, role-language, casual

In a japanese anime I've heard lots of "de gozaru" in a casual speech. If I use it with my friends, will it sound ok?

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25105/9831

Comment: Absolutely not unless you're deliberately trying to sound weird or make a joke.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about Prison School, aren't you? Gakuto is a comic relief "weirdo" character. He doesn't talk like modern Japanese. A lot of things he says is weird/uncommon these days, like 小生 and 皆の衆. (But if you're not talking about PS, then sorry, but it still stands that it'd be extremely weird to say でござる; imagine a friend of yours just starts saying stuff like ye, thou, thy, generally imitating a Shakespeare character).